# Click UIButton To Show UIPickerView and Select ID on Button Title : Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, uipickerviewcontroller

MY Scenario, I am trying to create button click to open `UIPickerView` and selecte picker data to show on button title using swift. Here, `Toolbar` also I would like to add into the pickerview controller.

```
 let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
  button.setTitle("",for: .normal)
  button.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(amount_textfield.frame.size.width - 9), y: CGFloat(5), width: CGFloat(9), height: CGFloat(20))
  button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refresh), for: .touchUpInside)
  amount_textfield.leftView = button
  amount_textfield.leftViewMode = .always

 @IBAction func refresh(_ sender: Any) {
    // Here, I need to execute picker view 
 }
```

Comment: see this for help ; https://peterwitham.com/swift-archives/how-to-use-a-uipickerview-as-input-for-a-uitextfield/

Answer (score 0):

There are few steps that you have to follow:

1. Create initially hidden `UIPickerView` and set its `delegate` and `dataSource`

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       pickerView.delegate = self
       pickerView.dataSource = self
   }
   ```
2. Have data source array which you use for this picker view

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController {
       var array = [String]()
   }

   extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
       func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
           return 1
       }
       func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
           return array.count
       }
       func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
           return array[row]
       }
   }
   ```
3. Unhide your picker view when button is pressed

   ```
   pickerView.isHidden = false
   ```
4. Integrate picker view's delegate method `pickerView(_:didSelectRow:inComponent:)`. When row is selected, set title of button as element from your data source array at index as selected `row`

   ```
   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
       button.setTitle(array[row], for: .normal)
   }
   ```
5. Optional: Hide picker view

   ```
   pickerView.isHidden = true
   ```

Comment: Thank you @Rober Dresler. Could you please post some code?

Comment: I need to show picker view controller bottom side. Above mentioned all code I have already. @Robert Dresler